# VS Code - unable to hide javascript files generated from typescript files

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I would like to hide the javascript files generated from the typescript files

This **works** perfectly:

[image]

With the following files structure:

[image]

(I have removed the exclude js files settings to show the structure)

However, if I change the file structure this way

[image]

The javascript files are **not hidden**

Anyone can help?

Comment: You can just hide the dist folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide the `dist` folder.
Better yet, I just exclude them from search:

```
// .vscode/settings.json
{
  "search.exclude": {
    "dist": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Great, that's what I wanted to achieve!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try this, Open your workspace settings file (.vscode/settings.json):
This will hide js files in every folder and it works even if you rename your `dist` folder to something else in future.

```
{
    "files.exclude": {
        "**/*.js": true,
        "**/*.map": true
    }
}
```